# @hocuspocus/server Notify user on backend fail

Tags: node.js, typescript, tiptap

I am using `onStoreDocument` hook in server configuration. From this hook I am making a database query to store the document.

I would like to notify the client UI in case database fails to save the update.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there any way (i.e. method) to somehow mark that the document is not synced on client side?
2. Can i send a message with error to the client? I saw [people reference](https://github.com/ueberdosis/hocuspocus/issues/605) `connection.sendStateless` but how can access it from `onStoreDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answers to my questions:

> Is there any way (i.e. method) to somehow mark that the document is not synced on client side?

You can get the boolean value from `provider.hasUnsyncedChanges`. For reactivity you can use `unsyncedChanges` event emitted on provider, i.e.:

```js
provider.on('unsyncedChanges', (n: number) => {
  console.log('Number of changes to send to server:', n);
});
```

> Can i send a message with error to the client? I saw people reference `connection.sendStateless` but how can access it from `onStoreDocument`?

`sendStateless` is on client side and accessible via `provider.sendStateless`.

for the server side we can use `document.broadcastStateless`. So `onStoredDocument` will look something like that:

```js
async onStoreDocument({ document }) {
  // saving to db...
  document.broadcastStateless('Saved!')
}
```